# CakePHP 2.1 bake test app and failed

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I download cakephp 2.1 from the official website. When I copied files to my www directory on Windows 7 64bit, (using WAMP 2.2 with PHP 5.3.8), and configured path to link to cake bake.bat in console folder I have problem. When I run cmd and typing cake bake testapp (to generate some test app and test new futures) I see in console strength error:

```
File app/View\Pages\home.ctp exists
Do you want to overwrite?
```

I answered y. The bake app is ready but If I type my localhost in my browser I see

> The action index is not defined in controller AppController

so I type manual pages to url I see 404!
Please help me because I want start a new project with new CakePHP 2.1 not 2.0.6...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is [fixed](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/b57489f3f1d08f600e947c0e535c32bcd2d7f956).

If you still getting error comment the following code in `C:\wamp\www\cake\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ProjectTask.php` file

```
if ($this->createHome($path)) {
                $this->out(__d('cake_console', ' * Welcome page created'));
            } else {
                $this->err(__d('cake_console', 'The Welcome page was <error>NOT</error> created'));
                $success = false;
            }
```

NOTE: `C:\wamp\www\cake` - This is my cake liberary path, change yours if its different.